# Show loading image without ajax

Tags: image

```
<img id="Img1" class="photoBox" src="Images/DisplayImageById.ashx?number=1&userName=<%=Page.User.Identity.Name %>"/>
         <img id="Img2" class="photoBox" src="Images/DisplayImageById.ashx?number=2&userName=<%=Page.User.Identity.Name %>"/>
         <img id="Img3" class="photoBox" src="Images/DisplayImageById.ashx?number=3&userName=<%=Page.User.Identity.Name %>"/>
         <img id="Img4" class="photoBox" src="Images/DisplayImageById.ashx?number=4&userName=<%=Page.User.Identity.Name %>"/>
         <img id="Img5" class="photoBox" src="Images/DisplayImageById.ashx?number=5&userName=<%=Page.User.Identity.Name %>"/>
```

I have been looking for a way to show a spinning icon until the images load without using ajax? I am researching how to load images using ajax but it wasn't going to well so I started looking for a way to do this without ajax. Is that possible?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Check this. This is done using jQuery's `load` event, which tells when a specific element is being loaded, in your case, `img`

http://jsfiddle.net/blackpla9ue/uJhCt/1/

```
$(function(){
  $('div img').each(function(){
    var thisImage = $(this);
    thisImage.hide(0)
             .load(function(){
                $(this).show();
             });
});
```

Note that this would **not** work if you put your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ...});`